# Lost Reputation from something I don't remember ever posting

Tags: discussion

the reputation loss is minimal (2 pts) but still, I can't remember the post responsible for it.

The log says:
-2 *removed* **How to Programming for Data Science by using KNN**

But I don't remember:

- Answering this post
- editing this post
- commenting this post
- this post at all

I am sure I didn't ask it, since I've never asked questions in Data Science Stack Exchange (other than meta)

Since it has been removed I can't find out what behavior costed me 2 points and can't improve my behavior since I don't know what happened.

Could any one help me finding out what I did that I should not repeat?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You suggested an edit on that post, which got deleted.

Here's [the query from SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/datascience/query/1032674):

> - Post Link: [How to Programming for Data Science by using KNN](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/48992)
> - User Link: [Pedro Henrique Monforte](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/users/70066)
> - Creation Date: 2019-04-09 20:10:04
> - Approval Date: 2019-04-10 01:22:52
> - Edit comment: removed generic images that makes the question too long and doesn't help to solve it

Since the post was deleted, the reputation gain from the suggested edit (+2) was undone.